# moment generating function an infinite moments

Tags: probability-theory, taylor-expansion, moment-generating-functions, provability

I consider a random variable which has moments $E[X^n]= \infty$.
Does this imply that the moment generating function does not exists?

How could I prove that?

The taylor series of mgf is: $E(e^{tX})= 1+ E(X) t + \frac{E(X^2) t^2}{2!} + ...$

This holds only for $t \in (-t_0,t_0)$ and $t_0>0$, where $E(e^{tX})< \infty$
see:

[Expected Value and Swapping integral and sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508569/expected-value-and-swapping-integral-and-sum)

If the moments are infinite can I conclude that mgf is infinite using the taylor series?

Comment: yes, moment generating function does not exist.

Comment: How can I show that?

Comment: This is just logical $M_X(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathbb E[X^n]}{n!}t^n.$ So, if $\mathbb E[X^n]=\infty $, the sum is not well defined.

Comment: But you use the fact that $E[e^{tX}]$ is finite for some t

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508569/expected-value-and-swapping-integral-and-sum

Comment: Is this not a contradiction?